# Can PostMessage make variables' changes in a worker thread visible in the UI thread after GetMessage?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

My question is actually that if I write a variable in another thread and then `PostMessage` to a Wnd, would `GetMessage` in the UI thread synchronizes with it and I can safely read the variable?

The background is: I want to update the UI from a background thread using `PostMessage`, and was worried about the data-race. Do I need other synchronization utilities?

Thanks.

EDIT:
The title is very confusing, so change it.

To elaborate the case:
Say I want to update a `std::string`, which is a global variable. Since I updates the `string` before `PostMessage`, Can I safely read the `string` in the Window Proc which processes that message?

I am familiar with the C++11 multi-thread terms like `happens-before`, `sequence-before`, `synchronize-with` and `release-acquire` concepts , so my question can be told the other way:

Does writing the `string` happens-before the reading?

PS: And assume this is a one-time thing, the worker thread won't update the `string` again and again.

Comment: What race condition is your concern? Since you are posting to a queue the messages will automatically be ordered in the way they were received.

Comment: @haohaolee, let me correct you a little. You shouldn't worry about data race. In your case you have no data race. You should worry about memory reads/writes reordering.

Comment: @AlexAntonov If I understand you correctly, you mean writes to the string can be reordered after `PostMessage`, right? But I think it must precede that because it sequences-before `PostMessage`, all the side effects should have happened to the string

Comment: @haohaolee The first thing I wanted to say is that you have no data-races (race conditions) in your code. A race condition occurs when two threads access the same memory area at the same time (and at least one thread is writing). In your program sequence [write to a string - PostMessage - receive the message - read from the string in another thread] the threads are accessing the string in different moments of time (you cannot receive message before it has been posted). So here is no possibility for a race condition (unless you write to the string after PostMessage e.g. you delete the string).

Comment: @haohaolee The only concern for me about thread safety in your case was a possibility of writes to the string to be reordered after `PostMessage` and after the reads from the string. But after thinking over your comment to my answer I agree with you that memory reads/writes reordering is not possible when using `PostMessage`. `PostMessage` is perfectly safe for posting structs between threads. For example SBM_SETSCROLLINFO message is sent/posted with a pointer to SCROLLINFO structure. It doesn't require any additional synchronization efforts when posting between threads... {to be continued}

Comment: @haohaolee ... And that means that writes to SCROLLINFO cannot be reordered after `PostMessage` and after reads from SCROLLINFO that is Windows provides synchronize-with relationship in some way.  
So you have no a race condition and you have no a reordering problem. Therefore your case is threadsafe and it doesn't require additional synchronization.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Message Queues are thread-safe producer-consumer queues. The MSG struct, (and only that), is COPIED into the queue, so once the message has been posted, you could reload your own message data and PostMessage again with no problem.

Issues arise with lifetime when developers PostMessage pointers/references as wParam, lParam.  If the pointer is to a local stack object, it can get RAII-ed away before the pointer to it gets handled in the receiving GetMessage/wndProc.  Similarly if a pointer to an object instantiated with new gets explicitly deleted in the posting thread before it is handled in the GetMessage thread.

If you give more details of what data you are PostMessaging, we should be able to advise you.

Answer (score 2):

No. You have zero control on that. `PostMessage` is truly asynchronous and by the time the message is processed, many things have happened in the two threads (including processing of prior posted message, and sent message (via SendMessage).

Depending of what you want to do, you may :

1. asynchronously transport a copy of the datas (`malloc`/`new`) and `PostMessage` (pointer in `wParam` or `lParam`)
2. synchronously transport a pointer to the datas with `SendMessage`
3. synchronously transport a copy of the datas with `SendMessage` and [WM_COPYDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649011.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It gives you a guarantee that the UI thread will consume the data and can safely update windows.  That's where that ends, you still have *another* thread that's reading data from a thread that writes the data so normal interlocking is required to ensure that the UI thread isn't reading *changing* data.

Which is a common enough problem, you cannot know exactly *when* the UI thread retrieves the message.  It can take a very long time if the UI thread is bogged down.  So unless you handshake this explicitly, you cannot know when your worker thread can continue updating the data or when it is okay to post another message.  Creating a deep copy of the data solves it.  Or you'll need an auto-reset event to handshake, beware of its ability to cause deadlock.

Another possible failure mode you'll have to deal with is that PostMessage() can fail.  Which will happen when the UI thread bogs down for any reason at all, you'll get a FALSE return whenever the message queue size exceeds the quota (10,000 messages by default).  Little you can do about it but sleep for a while and try again.

You'll also invoke this failure mode when you have a fire-hose problem, the worker thread producing data at a rate faster than the UI thread can ever keep up with.  Fire-hosing is particularly tricky since it rarely happens when you are starting out or debugging your program with a limited data set.  The diagnostic is the loss of WM_PAINT notifications, your UI appears to freeze even though it is still alive and actively processing the backlog of posted messages.  You avoid this by staying well north of the rate at which UI updates can be perceived by the human eye.  Which is nice and slow, it all turns into an unreadable blur when you update more than 25 times per second.

Comment: Heh - I have suffered from WMQ overloading a few times, usually when there is a treeview control involved and so the GUI updating is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of `PostMessage`/`GetMessage` provides no any guarantees about `synchronize-with` relationship. So even if the current/last version of Windows provided actually `synchronize-with` relationship for `PostMessage`/`GetMessage` on your hardware platform you shouldn't rely on it because it can be changed in newer versions of Windows or it may not work on other hardware platforms. So IMO in that particular case you have to provide `synchronize-with` relationship yourself to make your multithreading code bulletproof. For example you can do it with InterlockedXxx functions (they have both acquire and release semantics) or std::atomic.

Comment: Indeed the doc has nothing about synchronize-with relationship, but it's hard to image they don't synchronize with each other, because `GetMessage` sees the right message, it should be the one `PostMessage` posts